# Why am I getting this weird 'Mixed Content' Error?

Tags: html, pagespeed-insights, mixed-content

I am currently optimizing my website a little bit using, among other tools, PageSpeed Insights. In the "Best Practices" section i stumbled over a load of mixed content errors. The source on my website always regards embedded IFrames and looks as follows:

> homeimg02/description02.html:1:0(examplesite.de)

It also contains the following description:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://examplesite.de/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://www.formerexamplesite.de/404page.html'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I have no idea from where my page even pulls the old URL. To clarify, "formerexamplesite.de" was the url i used while writing and testing the site, but it now sits on "examplesite.de" and the old domain name appears nowhere in my code, i checked multiple times.

The "description02.html" is an embedded IFrame. There are no differing fonts used or loaded in that html document.

The fonts used are saved on the server and loaded in the style tag:

```
/* montserrat-600 - latin */
        @font-face {
                font-family: 'Montserrat';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 600;
                font-display: swap;
                src: local(''),
                    url('resources/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-600.woff2') format('woff2'),
                    url('resources/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-600.woff') format('woff');
                }
```

There are a couple dozen Errors like this, regarding different IFrames. I know using IFrames to embed stuff is not a good solution, but it was necessary in my situation, so other people could alter content on the webpage without touching the main document.

I'd like to understand what this error even tries to tell me and how I can fix it, if there is an error in my code causing this.

EDIT:
This comes up, when checking the browser requests.

```
Request URL:
https://examplesite.de/resources/homescreen/homeimg03/resources/fonts/montserrat-v25-latin-600.woff
```

I have the suspicion, that my pathing in the IFrame requesting the font might be wrong, as its set to local, thus creating this weird mess of a path. This still does not explain though, how the website gets my former domain name.

Comment: the mixed content error is exactly what you quoted. Even if you said that _formerexamplesite.de was the url i used while writing and testing the site, but it now sits on examplesite.de_ there may still be reference somewhere. do you have the complete codebase somewhere in local where you could `grep` the url string to find out the culprit?

Comment: if you need to make a more in depth investigation, you may also check the network tab in the developer tools while navigating the web site to see where are headed the actual http requests and which one is actually crossing the host boundaries

Comment: I checked every html document via ctrl+f for the old domain name and wrong paths, turned out nothing though.

Comment: if you know which one is the page having the problem, did you try to inspect the network requests performed to fetch all the resources? did you see anything being fetched from a different domain?

Comment: Edited the post, my pathing is probably wrong.

Comment: either serve everything on http or https., don't have a mixture of both - your iframe looks to have a source of `http://www.formerexamplesite.de/404page.html` so that and everything inside the iframe will most likely be served over http rather than https

Comment: The IFrame is hosted on the Same Server as the Main Site and does Not contain any Links to the former Website. Everything should be served via https.